# SSRS How to group the different series to new created category group

Tags: reporting-services

My data store in this way.

[image]

This is what I want to achieve.

[image]

I want to assign 2 bars to TY another 2 bars to LY, it is possible in SSRS?

Thanks !

Comment: Seriously I have been doing blind testing and also searching for solution but no idea at all. I know I could change the structure of the query but the same query is using by others chart and reporting so I would not consider to change the query for now, if there is a way to do.

Comment: If you have 4 value fields then you will have 4 data bars.

Comment: You need to get your data arranged so that you can group it by account (I assume) type. Why can't you change the query for this report?

Comment: HI Paul, because the same query is now using by others reports and chart, I want to add this chart to the existing report using, so I do not want to change the query, plus this query applied many rules so I try not to create another dataset with same rules but different structure

Comment: Hi Niktrs, Ya I need 4 data bars. What I want to achieve is to be able to group the 4 data bars to LY and TY which I am not sure whether it can be done in SSRS.